# problems with fitting sin curve to xslx data in python with scipy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to fit a sin curve to data read off an excel workbook using SciPy in python. I think most of the code is fine, but its having issues with being able to bound the curve for a certain set of data points (I've only defined my scatter plot to be for [0:20000] because I have a large data set), and I can't get the p0 parameters right to get a sin plot shape that fits with the data.

I'm not sure how to get the fit curve to only work over a certain range, and how to change the parameters to fit the initial data, I've tried many parameter combinations but they all produce this very low-amplitude curve in the image.

[code output showing the bounded initial data from excel in blue, and the curve fit in black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W99Sx.png)

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import fftpack as fft
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#%%
loc = "C:/Users/MARK/Downloads/CoupledPendulaDataNEW.xlsx"
sheet_name="25cm In Phase"
file = pd.read_excel(loc, sheet_name=sheet_name)
file.columns=['Time','Phi1','Phi2']
arrTime = np.array(file.Time)
arrPhi1 = np.array(file.Phi1)
arrPhi2 = np.array(file.Phi2)

#%%
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(file['Time'][0:20000],file['Phi1'][0:20000], label='Phi 1')

def test_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.sin(b * x) + c

pars, cov = curve_fit(test_func, arrTime, arrPhi1, p0=[1,10,0])
stdevs = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
res = arrPhi1 - test_func(arrTime, *pars)

plt.plot(arrTime, test_func(arrTime, *pars), linewidth=2, color='black')

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage signal (V)')
plt.title(sheet_name)
```

Comment: The problem is that even for something as __simple__ as a sine wave your initial guess better be a good one. Essentially it's super sensitive to your initial guess on `b`, which determines the frequency. If you know pretty well what that should be (at least within say 10-20%) you should be able to fix your problem completely.

Comment: @ALollz I'm fairly sure the voltage should be in terms of volts, as the blue curve is the data I'm trying to develop a curve_fit for, and the small black curve is the plot of the curve fit function, so the parameters shouldn't be on the scale of mV or uV, but I will try modifying the parameters again.